# AMD Radeon RX 6650 XT not recognized 22.04.1, need help gaining full potential

Tags: graphics, 22.04, amd-graphics, amdgpu, amdgpu-pro

Notwithstanding the fact that on a clean install of Ubuntu 22.04 and 22.04.1 I get all the same above unmet errors discussed
[Here] (https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/ROCm/issues/1713) (dependencies not met) when trying to install the latest drivers for a MSI Radeon RX 6650 XT card from AMD's site and following various iterations of amdgpu-install. I also get:

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: c1
       width: 64 bits
       **clock: 33MHz**
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 resolution=3840,2160
       resources: iomemory:7c0-7bf iomemory:7e0-7df irq:111 memory:7c00000000-7dffffffff memory:7e00000000-7e0fffffff ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fcc00000-fccfffff memory:fcd00000-fcd1ffff
redacted@redacted-PC:~$ lsmod | grep amd
edac_mce_amd           36864  0
amdgpu               9850880  22
iommu_v2               24576  1 amdgpu
gpu_sched              45056  1 amdgpu
drm_ttm_helper         16384  1 amdgpu
ttm                    86016  2 amdgpu,drm_ttm_helper
drm_kms_helper        311296  1 amdgpu
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 amdgpu
drm                   622592  15 gpu_sched,drm_kms_helper,amdgpu,drm_ttm_helper,ttm
```

Does the above indicate I have bigger issues with this card basically not being recognized at all by Ubuntu? Advice please! How do I utilize this card for gaming on Ubuntu? The performance is lack luster. Other specs of the PC is decent Ryzen 7, 36gb of RAM, decent M.2 SSD. Something feels terribly wrong.

Comment: the output you showed indicates that Ubuntu very much *does* recognize your card. The issue is with AMD's drivers: they are not properly suited to Ubuntu 22.04, and need to be fixed. There isn't anything you can do about that except wait (unless you want to work on developing/debugging the driver issues yourself).

Comment: regardless, you don't need these drivers in order for your card to run; there are drivers built-in that should work perfectly fine for gaming. These drivers are specifically for compute (AI and ML-type tasks), not for graphics rendering.

Comment: As for performance issues, you can open a new question and give *all* the details about what you're running, what performance is like and what you were expecting, and people can either help fix the issues or tell you if the performance is normal.

Comment: You did note the clock speed is recognized as 33Mhz? Surely that can't be right and is in part why this card is underperforming. So the drivers provided surely can't be sufficient for gaming as you state, no?

Comment: no, that seems pretty normal. GPUs don't run at nearly the same clock speeds as CPUs.   if you see, there is a line `configuration` and it says `driver=amdgpu`. That's the one you would use for gaming. Are you having actual problems with games? To confirm: the GPU is not under load when this was run, is that right? It should clock a bit faster when it is under load.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem. My RX 6650 XT was only running with about 25% performance. You need to install an additional driver:
http://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu-install/latest/ubuntu/jammy/

Then use this command for all os drivers:

```
amdgpu-install --usecase=graphics,opencl --vulkan=amdvlk
```

Reboot
(I also added oibaf PPA)

According to others, you also need latest linux-firmware (not in my case):
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=379001

My Basemark GPU Score (in Silent Mode) is **9395**. Before it was about **2400**.

```
System:
  Kernel: 5.15.0-46-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: GNOME 42.2
    Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)

Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD driver: amdgpu v: 5.16.9.22.20
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.1 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.1
    compositor: gnome-shell driver: X: loaded: amdgpu,ati
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,radeon,vesa gpu: amdgpu
    resolution: 2560x1440~60Hz
  OpenGL:
    renderer: AMD DIMGREY_CAVEFISH (LLVM 14.0.1 DRM 3.46 5.15.0-46-generic)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 22.1.0-devel
```

Comment: Thank you! Finally someone who gets it! I will try this and feedback. The problem is that the latest amdgpu drivers are incompatible with 22.04.1 and amd is aware of this and haven't yet implemented a fix. Please also review the thread I linked to with many users being unable to install amdgpu drivers due to unmet dependency errors.

Comment: Thank you! this worked! The ubuntu forum commentor was way off base. This increased by Basemark score to over 9424 as well (no baseline, sorry). It also increased my glmark2 --fulscreen benchmark from 5k to over 17k! Man, this was a painful month using this card at like a fraction of it's power!